# Are IPN updates necessary for PayPal buttons?

Tags: paypal-ipn, paypal-buttons

We received a notification from PayPal that ipn verification needs to be updated to https. 
https://www.paypal.com/au/webapps/mpp/ipn-verification-https

But we only use PayPal buttons generated from the PayPal website with some added drop down menus. Does this apply to us?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the IPN service, then you will need to update it to HTTPS. If not, there is no need for an update.

Comment: Are you using the PayPal buttons together with the IPN service? if no, then you got nothing to worry about. You may refer to https://www.paypal-notice.com/en/ for more info

Comment: I don't know what IPN service is. All i do is copy the HTML code from the generated button from PayPal website and insert on our website

Comment: Here is the documentation link for PayPal's Instant Payment Notification (IPN) - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/

Comment: If you're copy pasting the PayPal button code, then there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: I'm also adding a few text form fields that get passed onto PayPal. Not credit card numbers or sensitive information

Comment: It should not be a problem.